# The output of my grep Unix command is 1 even though it should be 24. Need help on how to fix this

Tags: unix, grep, command

So I need to count the number of females in an excel file column under SEX. I'm using this UNIX command code

```
grep -c "FEMALE" data.csv | wc -l
```

The output gives me 1. There are 24 times `FEMALE` is listed under the column SEX so the output should be 24. Any ideas on how to fix this?

I'm using Terminal on MAC. I've inputted

```
grep -o "FEMALE" data.csv | wc -1
```

and

```
grep -c "FEMALE" data.csv | uniq -wc
```

and

```
grep -c "FEMALE" data.csv | wc -l | uniq
```

already, and they all give me 1.

[image: CSV File]

Comment: `grep -ci "female" data.csv` is enough. You don't need `grep -c` **and** `wc`.

Comment: Thanks, just tried that and the output is still 1 instead of 24.

Comment: Please show your CSV then.

Comment: If your input file somehow messes up newlines, you can use `grep -oi 'female' data.csv | wc -l` to count occurrences, but if there are no newline problems, it really should be just `grep -ci 'female' data.csv`.

Comment: Please add sample input (no images) and your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: Benjamin, that worked! thanks. It gave me 24. The only issue now is that when I do input male instead of female to count the males, it gives me 61, the total of both male and female instead of just counting males. I used both grep -oi 'male' data.csv | wc -l  and grep -ci 'male' data.csv. it says male has no such file or directory.

Comment: That's because `female` contains `male`, so it'll count all these as well. To get only complete word matches, you can use the `-w` option: `grep -ciw 'male' data.csv`.

Answer (score 0):

Using this command only:

```
grep -c "FEMALE" data.csv
```